# Window 8 app Compile time error Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor in module System.dll

Tags: windows-8, json.net

I am building a very basic application for windows 8. Unfortunately i am receiving following error message.

> Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor in module
>   System.dll.

It is a compile time error message.
Can someone please explain why this is happening.?

Note. I am using Newtonsoft for json Parsing in this application

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, it appears that Newtonsoft uses the PropertyDescriptor object which is not currently supported for windows 8 / windows phones applications.  When I removed the Newtonsoft dll from my project I was able to build successfully (of course you'll have to find a work around for whatever you are using Newtonsoft for)